# Bash Shell "onecmd" Option Usage Purpose

Tags: bash, exit, set

I read on man page, but I don't understand the purpose of bash's `onecmd` option.  If I use the `set -o onecmd` command, the shell immediately exits. My expectation is for it to wait for me to enter one more command before exiting, but this does not happen.

So is this option just like the `exit` command?

Why does bash provide this option?

Can someone give me an example of how to properly use this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to why, I don't know, but note that you can set the options on the command line when starting the shell, e.g. here, the inner shell does read one command and then exits

```
bash$ PS1='onecmd$ ' bash -t 
onecmd$ echo moi;
moi
bash$
```

And also that it doesn't really exit after reading one command, but reads and executes at least one full *line*. Here's the same with two commands:

```
bash$ PS1='onecmd$ ' bash -t 
onecmd$ echo moi; echo hei
moi
hei
bash$
```

Of course, using e.g. `&&`, or wrapping the whole set of commands in `if true; then ... fi` would also work.